# How to prove this slightly changed "Egoroff's Theorem"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This problem has already been posted before on SE but I didn't get any satisfactory answer, so I have posted here again!

Here is the version of Egoroff's theorem in Royden's Real analysis: Let $E$ be a set of finite lebesgue measure, $f_{n}$ be a sequence that converges to a real valued function $f$  pointwise, on $E$.  Then for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set $A$ such that $m(E-A)<\epsilon$, and $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on A to $f$.

Now one of the exercise asks to prove the theorem in the following cases:

(1)$ f_{n} \to f$ pointwise a.e

(2) the limit function $f$ is finite a.e

I don't understand how to deal with these modifications? For the first one  , we have that the set on which $f_{n}$ doesnot converge to $f$ , say $A$, is of measure zero. So we can apply Egoroff's theorem on $E-A$. Then we get a closed set $B$ inside $E-A$ such that $f_{n}\to f$, uniformly $B$, and $m((E-A)-B)< \epsilon $ (say). But what I want is a closed set $F$ inside $E$, such that the conclusion of the theorem holds! How do I do that ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want a closed set inside A? That isn't what the theorem says...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it will be "E"

Comment: Hint: $(E - A)-B$ is the set of points which are in $E$ but not in $A$ and not in $B$, so $(E-A)-B =E-(A\cup B)$.